# Что такое "пустынь"?

Tags: этимология

Обычно пУстынями называют некоторые монастыри.
Но вот интересно, почему именно "пустынь"? К пустыне они отношения не имеют, да и места там обычно совершенно на пустыню не похожи. И какие именно монастыри так называют и почему?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fuchoin Kazuki, тут, собственно, slava1947 уже дал исчерпывающее определение, я только добавлю, что "пустыня" совершенно не обязательно должна быть похожа на пустыню, как мы её обычно понимаем (с песком и проч.). Пустыня - там где пусто, где нет постоянного населения. Там обычно и устраивали скитыю С монастырями - там немного сложнее, монастыбь - уже само по себе какое-то население, да и совершенно необязательно ему в пустыне быть, он сам по мебе "закрытое" учреждение, но в принципе смысл тот же: монастырь в п**у**стыни - вдалеке от цивилизации.

Answer (score 2):

> И какие именно монастыри так называют
> и почему?

*ПУСТЫНЬ - монастырь или скит, находящийся в отдаленном пустынном месте.*

http://days.pravoslavie.ru/Life/slovar2382.htm

Comment: @slava. Если бы ещё удалось подтвердить, что все монастыри-ПУСТЫНИ основывались именно в пустынных, не населённых местах. А факты об этом не свидетельствуют. Вот я цитирую абзац из публикации, посвящённой истории Оптиной пустыни: "От древнейших времен местность, где расположены город Козельск и Оптина, Пустынь была уже обитаема. Так, археологические раскопки 1899 года обнаружили здесь предметы каменного века. В исторические времена ее населяли племена вятичей, просвященные св. Кукшей (пострадавшим в Мценске в 1213 году)."

Answer (score 0):

Потому что отпУщеник, и отпущение грехов.  В лес уходили и уединялись, истово молясь. В пущу. Выходил из пущи -- отпущеник.
щ поменялось на СТ в латинской записи. Вместо пущи  стало пУсти, а потом и пУстинь, а потом по аналогии сравнялось с пустыня, осталось только ударение.

Comment: Ну с первой частью еще можно в чем-то согласиться: в части родственности "пуща" и "пусто", "пустыня". 

Но отпущеник - от отпустить. А это уже другой корень.
 
И причем тут вообще латынь?

Comment: Да? а пустить откуда? 
 А ведь  есть слова пущай,пущать, вот оттуда и разновидности той самой Латинизированной записи Щ-ST(SС) с заменой шипящей на комбинации, поскольку иначе никак,  сначала туда, потом обратно.  Получилось пускать и пустить.
Когда у человека два алфавита в башке, да без учебников, он и не то напишет.
Борщ-Borschtsch   это  как пример такого, скажем монашеского, произвола и туда назад перетолмачивания на бумаге. А точнее один у другого копировал до безобразия.

Comment: пущать пуща́ть "пускать", ст.-слав. поуштати παραπέμπειν, πέμπειν (Супр.), болг. пу́щам, сербохорв. пу̏штати, пу̏шта̑м, словен. púščati, рúščаm, чеш. pouštěti, слвц. рúšt᾽аt᾽, польск. puszczać, в.-луж. pušćeć, н.-луж. pušćiś. От пусти́ть (см.). Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Цепочка прозрачна и причины изменений тоже ясны, постоянные попытки экспансии латыни с ее алфавитом.
Если есть другие мысли, просьба изложить, обсуждение продолжить.

Ссылки на бред, задорновщину, троллинг и прочую билиберду не принимаются.

Comment:  @behemothus. ПУЩА и ПУСТО,ПУСТЫНЯ не родственны  , а только схожи по созвучию . Смотрите мой ОТВЕТ .

Answer (score 0):

Давайте посмотрим ПУСТЫНЬ по схожим словам в "Полном церковно-славянском словаре" магистра Г. Дьяченко.

**Стр.525**: ПУСТЫЙ - лишенный всего, ничего не имеющий; ПУСТЫННОЛЮБИВЫЙ - склонный к пустынной жизни, к уединению /[link text](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0525.htm)/.

**Стр.527**: ПУЩЕННИКИ - церковные люди /[link text](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0527.htm)/. **Церковные люди** - это люди, не входящие в штат служителей церковного храма, но активно помогающие храму в его деятельности.

Последнее значение - **ПУЩЕННИКИ** -   указывает на то, что монастыри-ПУСТЫНИ  основывались определённой категорией верующих-подвижников, а именно: *верующими, не имевшими ранее какого-либо духовного звания, т.е. мирянами-активистами* = **церковными людьми** = **пущенниками**. То, что Щ = СТ, я уже писал в своём исследовании "Вариации СТ/ШТ - Щ" [link text](https://rus.stackexchange.com/research/41092/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82-%D1%88%D1%82-%D1%89) //// Что касается слова ПУЩА, то этот же источник определяет его как "лес" и выводит происхождение из санскрита /в прибавлениях П [link text](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_1096.htm) /.

Comment: Ответ так себе, вы занимаетесь голым сравнением, это не дело. link  ваш прочел  и ужаснулся, там еще комментарии есть, и я их поддерживаю..  У вас напрочь отсутствуют причины того или иного перехода от слова к слову. А логика заставляет анализировать и делать многофакторный анализ этих причин.   например, отсутствие зубов и шепелявость, причины шепелявости, по археологии пройтись. с датировками разобраться, с имеющимся историческим материалом, а тогда и заниматься этим делом, собственно языком и его историей. А копирование предыдущих высказываний--это не труд, ума не надо, сноровка,

Comment: С какой такой стати пущенники, помогающие храму в его деятельности, влруг, с вашей, пардон, бухты барахты и основали этот храм-пустынь. логикА? впечатляет ее отсутствие, зато воображение на должном уровне. не знаю где ваш источник откопал, но вот в этом словаре http://www.slovarus.info/sns.php#1 
лес 
अरण्यम्
araṇyam
(n) jungle, forest

कानन
kānana

forest

कलिलं
kalilaṃ

dense forest

वन
vana

forest

वनं
vanaṃ



दारु
dāru
(neut) tree, wood

काष्ठ
kāṣṭha

(neut) piece of wood

मलयज 1
malayaja

a sandal tree (born in malaya mountain range), sandal wood

Comment: @petro. Батенька! Если уж говорить о слабости логики в моем Ответе, то уязвимое звено не в том, что Вы там наплели про историч. материал, а в другом: кого называли ПУЩЕННИКами/церковными людьми. Я высказал предположение, что "церковные люди" это миряне-активисты. Однако, возможно, что это были бездомные нищие, жившие при церкви(храме). Из того же источника, который Вы охаяли: "ПУСТЫЙ - лишенный всего, ничего не имеющий". Если обратиться к истории Оптиной пустыни, то по легенде её основал покаявшийся разбойник Опта, крещённый как Макарий (Макарьевская - её 2-е название)...

Comment: @petro. ... Покаявшийся разбойник Опта/Макарий несомненно должен был представлять из себя такого "лишенного всего,  ничего не имеющего".  И вполне вероятно,  что и жил он в покаянии при какой-то церкви,  замаливая грехи.  А потом основал скит,  преобразовавшийся в монастырь.  Вторая точка зрения,  параллельная 1-й,  вполне логична,  также,  как и 1-я,  высказанная в Ответе.

Answer (score -2):

Пустынь. Если быть уж очень дотошным, то это слово описывает психоэмоциональное состояние человека. С материальной точки зрения, это место, где находится бьющий из земли источник, вода в котором обладает лечебными свойствами (преимущественно к кожным заболеваниям).  Р S. информация к размышлению. Для тех кто ставит минусы не думая ."Исцеления у святых источников Курской Коренной пустыни"Будучи в монастыре Коренная пустынь, что в сорока километрах от Курска, я слышал об исцелении  больных от купания в святых источниках и приема воды из них. А на территории монастыря Коренная пустынь их более шестнадцати. Здесь есть и источник, в котором исцелился Серафим Соровский, есть источник «Пантелеймона-целителя». Все шестнадцать святых источников стекают в реку, воды которой, протекая по заповедным местам, считаются также целебными.....